# Determination of Open Covers

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know whether the following set is an open cover of R :

Case I :

G = { ]n,n+1[ : n belongs to Z}

My Approach and Contradiction arrived:

Now consider the case for n=1 and n=2

Then we have,

]1,2[ and ]2,3[ as the intervals but here 2 belongs to R but doesn't belong to either of the interval or the union of both of these intervals.Well is it right if I say that this set is not an open cover of R.

Case II:

A similar case with this set where :

J = { ]1/n+2 , 1/n[ : n belongs to N } for the set ]0,1[.

In this case,  I made subsequent intervals as follows :

]1/3 ,1[ , ]1/4 ,2[ ..............as n tends to infinity 1/n tends to 0.
So I think for any x not equal to 0, I can always find a number greater than zero which lies in ]0,1[. Is my reasoning feasible or Do I need a rigorous one  for the same?

Answer (score 1):

You have to prove that for any $x\in\ ]0,1[\ $ you can find an interval $I_n$ in your collection $J$ such that $x\in I_n$.

As $\lim_{n\to\infty}{1\over n+2}=0$ the set of $n\geq1$ with ${1\over n+2}<x$ is nonempty, hence has a minimal element $n_x$. If $n_x=1$ then ${1\over3}<x<1$, hence $x\in I_1$. If $n_x\geq2$ then
$${1\over n_x+2}<x\leq{1\over (n_x-1)+2}<{1\over n_x}\ ,$$
and this implies $x\in I_{n_x}$.

Answer (score 0):

Case I: it does not cover $\mathbb{R}$

Case II:

J = { ]1/n+2 , 1/n[ : n belongs to N } for the set ]0,1[.

is not what you have calculated.

The intervals you have written is the set

$$ J = \left\{\left]\frac{1}{n+2}; n\right[\ : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
PS: It's not clear what you mean by "for the set ]0,1[".

PPS: the $J$ I have defined and the $J$ you have defined will never cover $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: My bad( for mistake)! My question meant that can J = { ]1/n+2 , 1/n [ : n € N} cover the set ] 0 ,1 [ ?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\frac{1}{n+2}$ and not $\frac{1}{n}+2$ as you have written :-p ($\frac{1}{n}+2$ is bigger than $1/n$).
if my assumption is correct then yes it does cover ]0,1[.
for every x, if 1/n < x < 1/(n+1) for some n then x is in $]\frac{1}{n+1+2}, \frac{1}{n+1}[$ (if x = 1/n for some n, it is in the set with n+1.
And one of these two casses is always true for some n.

However the most natural way for me of covering $]0,1[$ is the set $J = \{]\frac{1}{n}, 1-\frac{1}{n}[\}$